# How to exclude specific methods from a "keep" rule in ProGuard?

Tags: proguard

I'm running ProGuard on a library. To keep public methods and attributes from shrinkage and obfuscation, I'm using this rule:

```
-keep public class com.company.project.** {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}
```

I need to make a few exceptions to this rule - methods that I actually need to be shrinked/obfuscated regularly by ProGuard. Is that possible? What would be the syntax for that?